# Competion Problem in graph theory

Tags: graph-theory, problem-solving

How can I prove that every graph has two vertices which are endpoints of the same number of edges? Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** You can apply the *pigeonhole principle*.

> Let $n$ be the number of vertices. Associate to each vertex the set of
>  vertices connected to it. There are $n$ such sets, and each of them
>  has at most $n - 1$ elements. Thus, we can conclude that there are two
>  sets with the same number of elements, and their corresponding
>  vertices are endpoints of the same number of edges.

Comment: Good hint (I appreciate the spoiler syntax very much!). Now I realize that it was so easy.